# Firefox radio buttons not checking?

Tags: html, css, angularjs, firefox

I have an angularJS application working fine in Chrome and IE (YES i said IE!!) but firefox doesnt seem to be showing the radio buttons as checked.  I have checked the html (image below) and it seems fine, but as you can see the radio button is still showing as unchecked.

[image]

I have looked on the web and people say there is a bug in firefox with radio buttons but not sure if its the same bug here, and i have added the autocomplete="off" to both my form and radio buttons but still no luck.

Anyone else got a fix for this?

Comment: Can you isolate the problem? Is it angular related at all? Or maybe some CSS quirk? Can you replicate it in standalone demo?

Comment: can you please provide fiddle for this ?

Comment: Instead of JSFiddle, use the StackOverflow Code Snippet: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Comment: Are you using a CSS framework or styling your own radio buttons ? On Firefox, my radio buttons look different. You might have a CSS issue. I tried the sample code on the AngularJS's homepage replacing checkboxes with radio buttons and it was working perfectly.

Comment: that is a good point, i am using bootstrap... i will try and make a fiddle to see if i can replicate

Answer (score 0):

Given the timing of your question could be related to firefox bug that was in v33? https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/10089#issuecomment-63296014

If it doesn't happen in ff36 or above probably related.